# Issue With Math Function Called From Another File

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a unit conversion calculator, and wanted to make it smoother by calling the math functions from a different file. Currently, Celsius -> Fahrenheit (CF) is put in 'func.py', like this:

```
# This file has all the math functions that get called by main.py when needed.
# Also, VARIABLES!
num = 0
typ = 0

def CF():
  tota = (num * 9/5) + 32
  print("Answer: " + str(tota) + " degrees Fahrenheit")
```

And the code to call it in main.py looks like this:

```
if (typ == str('C-F')):
  num = int(input("Enter the temperature in Celcius: "))
  num = num
  CF()
```

I figure that I imported something wrong, but I've edited the import function several times now. I'm not looking for some type of complete correction, I wish for somebody to tell me what I did wrong, so that *I* can fix it. I used repl.it, if it helps. Even if someone can tell me that it's possible, it'll help.

I couldn't find anything on websites like GeeksforGeeks, which is my main source on research.

Comment: What does your file structure look like and what are your imports?

Comment: What's the error you get when running main.py?

Comment: I didn't get an error, actually. It just doesn't show the solution. As for my imports, `from func import CF` and it's just main.py and func.py

Comment: The problem is that every file has its own variables. You can do `func.num = num` before calling the function, but the *beter* solution is to use function parameters and returns (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very odd:

```
def CF():
```

You're relying on `num` being defined at module scope within its module.
Much better to [spell](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) it this way, so you're passing in an argument:

```
def cf(num):
```

Over in `main.py` you're doing this, which isn't helpful:

```
num = num
```

Much better to pass it in:

```
cf(num)
```

---

The big concept you've been missing is you have two different modules,
and each one has a `num` variable.
They are different.
Changing one won't automatically affect the other.

Use function parameters instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with function parameters and returns (see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_function_arguments.asp) for a tutorial).

```py
# func.py
def CF(num):
  return (num * 9/5) + 32
```

```py
# main.py
if (typ == str('C-F')):
  num = int(input("Enter the temperature in Celcius: "))
  tota = CF(num)
  print("Answer: " + str(tota) + " degrees Fahrenheit")
```